# Dynamics 365 CRM Getting a two optionset value (yes or no) and using it to disable all form fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

in Dynamics 365 CRM form there's a checkbox field named opu_paid,
if its unchecked, im supposed to disable all fields in the form in javascript.
so far im stuck in my code on how to get the value from this checkbox field (wether its true or false)
so i can use "setDisabled" method

How do i get the the checkbox field value ?

```
var formContext = Context.getFormContext();
var paidCheckbox = formContext.getAttribute("opu_paid").getValue() // this is not working 

if(!paidCheckbox)
{
    formContext.getControl("firstname").setDisabled(true);
    formContext.getControl("lastname").setDisabled(true);
}
else
{
    formContext.getControl("firstname").setDisabled(false);
    formContext.getControl("lastname").setDisabled(false);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use business rules to solve the problem?

Comment: also check the schema name of your field, it has no prefix, maybe it's `new_paid` for example?

Comment: i've edited the post, and i need to learn how to do it in code; ive done it in business rules its rather easy

Comment: check if there's any error in the browser console, also check the value of the `paidCheckbox` variable in the browser debugger

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your attribute name is wrong.  Attributes will either be OOB attributes or are required to have a prefix of "something_" to it.

What you have is correct otherwise.  If you need more help, you'll need to provide better details like what is getValue() returning?  How is it not working?

Comment: Yes it has a prefix but removed it on purpose; thought i'd ask "in general";
edited the name in the question,
and the getvalue is supposed to return true or false as the options are either "no" valued 0, or "yes" valued 1
it should disable first name last name fields if the option is "no", enable otherwise

Comment: So what is it returning?